# WSO2 IS: Error using OAuth Authorization Code flow with SOAP API

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using the OAuth Authorization Code flow to authenticate the user and authorize my application against the WSO2 Identity Server. I'm using a simple node/express server, with Passport.js, to get the Access Token, and Postman to use that Access Token to make a few test requests to the SOAP APIs.

When using a Bearer Token method to authorize my application, I get the following error in the IS logs: `0 active authenticators registered in the system. The system should have at least 1 active authenticator service registered.` I get the following error in Postman: `500 Internal Server Error`, with the following response body, `<faultstring>Authentication failure</faultstring>`.

Here is what it looks like in Postman:
[image]

The same Access Token works with a REST API request, like "https://localhost:9443/scim2/Me".

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: OAUTH doesn't have '-', can you remove '-' from the token and try again, meanwhile can you tell me whether in REST API, are you passing '-' in the token field or not

Comment: Hi @amg_amit, thanks for your response! I'm using the exact same access token, including the dashes (-), for the REST endpoint, and I get the expected user data returned. I've tried removing the dashes in the token for both requests, and both fail when I do so.

Comment: In Postman, there is a header tab can you select that and paste the header values,This Header is next to the Authorization tab

Comment: Hi @amg_amit, here are the header values:

Authorization: Bearer 873b4a13-a49b-321f-b43b-7a5e8eb6fc59
Content-Type: text/xml

Comment: I should probably also mention that the request works if I use Basic Auth instead.

Comment: Then this will not work as OAUTH token is different and Basic Auth is different,How did you get this token is any application generating this token? If yes then try to open the URL of that application in your browser

Comment: I'm using my own Service Provider for the Identity Server to generate the token. It's a simple Node.js/Express.js/Passport.js server that correctly authenticates and provides the access token. And I can know that the access token is correct, since it works in Postman when I use it for one of the REST API endpoints, like https://localhost:9443/scim2/Me.

Comment: As i see that you are using WSO2 IS, i would recommend that you first call the IS service from postman, by passing request like "client-id, client-secret" e.t.c, once you get the token, try using this token for testing

Comment: Thanks @amg_amit, I'll try that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174647/discussion-between-mtl-and-amg-amit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP APIs in WSO2 Identity Server cannot be authenticated with Bearer tokens. They can be authenticated with Basic authentication and cookies. That's the reason for getting `Authentication failure` in the response.

But REST APIs in the Identity Server can be authenticated with Bearer tokens. So `/scim2/Me` authenticate successfully with access token.

Comment: Hi Manduranga, thank you for your response. I'm a little confused about how to get a secure OAuth authorization flow to work. If I'm using OAuth2.0 to authenticate the user against IS, then all I have is a Bearer Token, correct? So how would I use the SOAP APIs with OAuth2.0 Authorization Code flow?

Comment: After the user authentication, if you need to get user information, you can use OIDC, instead of OAuth 2.0. If you want do some user management functionality, you can use SCIM 2 REST APIs. If you explain your actual use case, I would be able to help you easily.

Comment: I'm looking to replicate the functionality of the current dashboard in terms Approval Workflows and as well as Associated Accounts. It looks like you can't get the necessary functionality from the SCIM2 REST API. What auth flow do recommend for this? I'm not experienced with SOAP, so any help is appreciated :).

Comment: You have to use basic authentication or cookies to get your scenario to work.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know. It wasn't apparent from the documentation. One final question: What exactly do you mean when you say "or cookies". Can you perhaps refer me to some documentation on this?

Comment: And I see you work for WSO2. Perhaps you know where I can find comprehensive documentation on authorizing users agains the SOAP APIs? I've searched through the docs and haven't yet found what I've been looking for.

Comment: See https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Calling+Admin+Services to get a better idea about authenticating users for SOAP APIs

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the Access token manually from Authorize service and use it

Step 1: Get authorization code

`https://<is_server_url>:9443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<id>&redirect_uri=<callback_url>&response_type=code&scope=openid`

You will get an authorization code on the callback URL

Step 2: Call token service to get access token

```
Post https://<is_server_url>:9443/oauth2/token
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:Basic <base64encoded "<client_id>:<client_secret>">

grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid
code:<code_from_step_1>
redirect_uri:<callback_url>
```

exp:

```
client_id=**abcdefgh12345678**
client_secret=**xyzsecretkey**
callback_url=**http://locahost/callback**
scope=openid
```

server: **localhost**
base64encode(client_id:client_secret)= base64encode(***abcdefgh12345678***:***xyzsecretkey***) => **YWJjZGVmZ2gxMjM0NTY3ODp4eXpzZWNyZXRrZXk=**

1. **GET** `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=**abcdefgh12345678**&redirect_uri=**http://locahost/callback**&response_type=code&scope=openid`

it will make a request back to the callback url with a parameter code, lets say code=**this01is02your03code**, please check your browser address bar

2. **POST** https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

**HEADERS**

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Authorization:Basic **YWJjZGVmZ2gxMjM0NTY3ODp4eXpzZWNyZXRrZXk=**
```

**BODY**

```
grant_type:authorization_code

scope:openid

code:this01is02your03code

redirect_uri:http://locahost/callback
```

this will return an access token, let say token returned by the server is **12345678ASDFGH**

Now you could use this token to call any RestFull or SOAP service

```
Authorization: Bearer 12345678ASDFGH
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, it look like Maduranga's response above is correct, in that you actually can't use a Bearer Token to authorize agains the SOAP APIs.